# How to make query in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to make a code user id with my style, but i confuse to make it in Yii 2.
Can you help me, how write the query like this code below in Yii 2.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "select * from `$tbadmin` order by `kode_admin` desc";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$jum = mysql_num_rows($q);
$kd = "ADM";
if ($jum > 0) {
    $d = mysql_fetch_array($q);
    $idmax = $d["kode_admin"];
    $urut = substr($idmax, 3, 2) + 1; //01
    if ($urut < 10) {
        $idmax = "$kd" . "0" . $urut;
    } else {
        $idmax = "$kd" . $urut;
    }
} else {
    $idmax = "$kd" . "01";
}
$kode_admin = $idmax;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$model = AdminModelName::find()->orderBy('kode_admin DESC')->asArray()->all();

foreach($model as $m) {

     $m->kode_admin = $this->createKode();
     $m->save();

  }
```

Comment: Could you provide an explenation with your code? It might help OP or future users more.

Answer (score 2):

```
$model = Admin::find()->orderBy(['kode_admin DESC'])->all();
foreach($model as $m) {
  $m->kode_admin = $this->createKode();
  $m->save();
}
```

Admin is the model for `tbadmin` table, and `createKode` could be a function in your controller.

If your are creating a new Admin:

```
$model = new Admin();
$model->kode_admin = $this->createKode();
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

create model with [Gii Tools](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-gii-index.html)

```
 $model = \app\models\tbadmin::find()
                            ->select()
                            ->orderby(['kode_admin => SORT_DESC',])
                            ->all();
```

Comment: I have tha model, and i did't wan't to use auto increment on database in this case. So, i make a code like above, but i confuse to realize in Yii 2.
So, what should i do?.